# Is it valid to hide implementation using inheritance on the base class?

Tags: c++

My class has a lot of private objects and I find it annoying to touch the header every time I change the private implementation. Is below valid? gcc and clang didn't seem to complain about it. The suspect part is when I create the object using Oscar and typecast it in DoSomething, however I have a static assert to prevent dumb accidents

main.h

```
class Oscar {
protected:
    int _a=0, _b=0;
public:
    //Common function that is used in many files
    int a() { return _a; }
    int a(int val) { return (_a=val); }
    int Work(int val) { _b += val; return _a + _b; }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
class OscarImpl : public Oscar {
public:
    //Complex and private functions only used in this file
    int MoreWork(int val) {
        return _a*val + _b;
    }
};
static_assert(sizeof(OscarImpl) == sizeof(Oscar));

int DoSomething(Oscar&o_) {
    auto&o=*(OscarImpl*)&o_;
    return o.MoreWork(25);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Oscar obj;
    return DoSomething(obj);
}
```

Comment: `auto&o=*(OscarImpl*)&o_; return o.MoreWork(25);` is a strict aliasing violation.  Whille a derived is a base, a base is not a derived.  The c-style cast should be an indicator you are doing something you shouldn't.

Comment: No, this is absolutely invalid. `o_` does not refer to `OscarImpl`.

Comment: Side note: [PIMPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) may be of use to you.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, is there anything that says I may alias in the situation I shown? I vaguely remember someone saying you may break the alias restriction with memcpy but my case both objects are the same size and have no virtual methods

Comment: @273K do you have a suggestion? Would my code be 100% valid if I changed main to use `OscarImpl` instead?

Comment: Since the *"Complex and private functions"* are *"only used in this file"*, why do they have to be members of `OscarImpl`? Is it only to access protected members of `Oscar` (which could also be accomplished with a `friend` class instead of a derived class)?

Comment: I don't understand what your aim is. The implementation is hidden in the .cpp file. What are you trying to hide? It looks like the XY problem.

Comment: @273K: First sentence of my post. Along with most of the functions are used in a single file which is why I want to replace much of it with an impl class "My class has a lot of private objects and I find it annoying to touch the header every time I change the private implementation"

Comment: @NathanOliver Can you cite the standard? IIRC alias rules apply when a pointer points to two different types, there's no virtual here and the data members are all the same types. Unless someone can cite something I'm assuming people are guessing and it's not true

Comment: There is nothing "hidden" or "private" here, both will be complete types, and Oscar will hold the data which means i can inherit from it and modify its invariances, wrost of all your functions will still treat me as OscarImpl if i created my own Foo that inherits from Oscar and pass it instead, you are better off using either Pimp idiom or Interfaces if you want to "hide" anything, if you don't want to hide anything then put the implementation in your free functions and avoid the C style cast.

Comment: I'm guessing that the `static_assert` is attempting to verify that the derived class doesn't have any data members of its own. That won't work; there is no requirement that a derived class with data takes up more space than its base, and there are reasonable approaches that a compiler could take that would trigger the assert incorrectly. For example, the base class could (and often does) have padding, so it's larger than the minimum needed for its data. The derived class could then put its data in that padding, so it would be the same size.

Comment: @PeteBecker clever. I guess I really should make sure I create all my objects with OscarImpl. I'm using this strategy as a refactor so hopefully the code becomes reasonable once I'm done. Its not reasonable right now

Comment: @AndrewSpar The section of the standard that forbids this can be found [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.static.cast#2).  The last two sentences are what applies here: *If the object of type “cv1 B” is actually a base class subobject of an object of type D, the result refers to the enclosing object of type D. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.*  Since `o` refers to a base class object and not a base class subobject of an derived class the cast has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`(OscarImpl*)&o_` has undefined behavior. It is equivalent to `static_cast<OscarImpl*>(&o_)`.

`o_` points to a `Oscar` object that is not a subobject of a `OscarImpl` object. `static_cast` has undefined behavior if the object pointed-to by the operand isn't actually a base class subobject of an object of the target type.

> gcc and clang didn't seem to complain about it

This is rule violation that the compilers can't really detect because it depends on what exactly you are passing the function. Additionally, using a C-style cast is generally understood by the compiler as you telling it "*do not complain about this, I know what I am doing*". C-style casts should be avoided in C++.

> `static_assert(sizeof(OscarImpl) == sizeof(Oscar));`

This assertion doesn't help in any form btw. The situation is neither necessarily better nor worse if that is not satisfied.

Comment: IIRC if the UB san doesn't complain it's safe to use in clang. If I made sure I never created an instance of Oscar and always used OscarImpl would my code be correct? Are pointer cast not `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @AndrewSpar "_if the UB san doesn't complain it's safe to use in clang_": Absolutely not. UBSan diagnosis only a small number of common and easy to diagnose undefined behaviors. Diagnosing a wrong cast in general is not practically feasible.

Comment: @AndrewSpar "_If I made sure I never created an instance of Oscar and always used OscarImpl would my code be correct?_": Yes, but conceptually it seems that you are misusing classes. It doesn't make sense for some methods of a class to only be relevant to one translation unit. If the extension of the class is really only relevant in the one translation unit, then why does `DoSomething` take a `Oscar&` instead of a `OscarImpl&` anyway?

Comment: "_Are pointer cast not reinterpret_cast?_": It depends on multiple factors. A C-style cast goes through a list of C++-style casts and uses the first that is able to perform the cast. In case of pointers that may either result in a `static_cast` or a `reinterpret_cast`, both with very different semantics and usually at most one of them correct (i.e. without UB). That's one reason why C-style casts are so dangerous. Most users are probably not going to be aware of the intricate rules behind it.

Comment: I'm trying to refactor code. The object I'm working with has a lot of public object and a lot of friend classes. If it was legal I'd use it as an easy to deal with solution. Since it isn't, it may be much harder to refactor

Comment: @AndrewSpar It would all be fine if `DoSomething` took a `OscarImpl&` instead of a `Oscar&` as parameter and if the name was rather something like `OscarExtended`. (It still probably wouldn't result in a good class design though, because the extended class depends on the implementation details of the base class.)

Comment: @AndrewSpar *"IIRC if the UB san doesn't complain it's safe to use in clang."* -- Even if this was true, it would be irrelevant to your question. You asked if it was **valid**, not if it was "safe" given a specific compiler. (A compiler is allowed to define behavior that the standard leaves undefined.)

Comment: I'm certain everyone is wrong since noone can cite the standard, Aliasing is about different types overlapping. All the members of the class are the correct type and there's no virtual data

Comment: @AndrewSpar It has nothing to do with aliasing. That's correct. But it is still UB and the layout doesn't matter at all: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#12.sentence-5, https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#4

Comment: @user17732522 thanks. I'll want to read the entire thing when I'm more awake. It seems like "where D is a complete class derived from B" is one of the key points, I'd argue that D is complete in my example. (fyi I can't upvote when my rep)

Comment: @AndrewSpar "_complete_" means that the class has been defined. If it was incomplete (i.e. declared, but not defined), then the cast would not be possible as the compiler would have no way to know about the inheritance relation. It can't see that the class will be derived of the other in the future definition that it hasn't seen yet. In that case the C-style cast would fall through to a `reinterpret_cast`, which will then cause another form of UB later (and that one would be equivalent to an aliasing violation in C, although that is actually narrower defined in C++).